# Reportlab Not Generating Charts in a Django App on Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, reportlab

I have a django app running on google app engine. One function of the app is to produce charts based on data given to it while using the app. I used reportlab to produce the charts, and this worked during development. However, on uploading the app to Google App Engine, any attempt to view the chart pages returns the following error:

"**ImportError at ...
No module named _renderPM**"

So far, I have learnt that the error is as a result of reportlab's reliance on PIL which isn't supported by GAE. I have placed the reportlab module in the app's project directory, but it still doesn't work.

Therefore, my question is: What do I need to do to make the charts viewable on the app? Is there anyway to make reportlab work on GAE as required by my app?

(The codes for the app's "mycharts.py" and "views.py" are shown below.)

## mycharts.py

```
from reportlab.graphics.shapes import Drawing, String
from reportlab.graphics.charts.barcharts import VerticalBarChart
from reportlab.graphics.charts.linecharts import HorizontalLineChart
from reportlab.graphics.charts.lineplots import LinePlot
from reportlab.graphics.widgets.markers import makeMarker
from reportlab.graphics.charts.textlabels import Label
from reportlab.graphics.widgets.grids import Grid, DoubleGrid
from reportlab.lib import colors
from models import Caller

#Customer gender filter functions begin here
def male_caller_count():
    return Caller.objects.filter(gender='Male').count()

def female_caller_count():
    return Caller.objects.filter(gender='Female').count()
#Customer gender filter functions end here

class GenderChartDraw(Drawing):
    def __init__(self, width=500, height=500, *args, **kw):

        Drawing.__init__(self,width,height,*args,**kw)

        female = female_caller_count()
        male   = male_caller_count()

        data = [(male, 0), (0, female)]

        self.add(VerticalBarChart(), name='chart')
        self.add(String(100,450,'Caller by Gender'), name='title')
        self.title.fontName = 'Helvetica-Bold'
        self.title.fontSize = 20

        self.chart.x = 70
        self.chart.y = 20
        self.chart.width = 300
        self.chart.height = 400
        self.chart.data = data
        self.chart.strokeColor = colors.black
        self.chart.valueAxis.valueMin = 0
        self.chart.valueAxis.valueMax = 50
        self.chart.valueAxis.valueStep = 5
        self.chart.valueAxis.visibleGrid = 1
        self.chart.categoryAxis.style = 'stacked'
        self.chart.categoryAxis.categoryNames = ['Male', 'Female']
        self.chart.bars[0].fillColor = colors.HexColor('#376BF9')
        self.chart.bars[1].fillColor = colors.HexColor('#FE03E5')
        self.chart.categoryAxis.labels.fontSize = 13

if __name__=='__main__':
    #use the standard 'save' method to save barchart.gif, barchart.pdf etc
    #for quick feedback while working.
    GenderChartDraw().save(formats=['gif','png','jpg','pdf'],outDir='.',fnRoot='barchart')
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from datetime import datetime
from models import Caller
import mycharts
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def app_stats(request):
    return render_to_response('AppStats.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))

@login_required
def gender_chart(request):
    #instantiate a drawing object
    d = mycharts.GenderChartDraw()

    if 'height' in request:
        d.height = int(request['height'])
    if 'width' in request:
        d.width = int(request['width'])

    if 'numbers' in request:
        strNumbers = request['numbers']
        numbers = map(int, strNumbers.split(','))    
        d.chart.data = [numbers]   #bar charts take a list-of-lists for data

    if 'title' in request:
        d.title.text = request['title']

    #get a GIF (or PNG, JPG, or whatever)
    binaryStuff = d.asString('gif')
    return HttpResponse(binaryStuff, 'image/gif')
```

## Error log

```
ImportError at /CallApp/stats/GenderChart/
No module named _renderPM
see https://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/rl-addons/
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://cacallapp.appspot.com/CallApp/stats/GenderChart/
Django Version: 1.4.3
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named _renderPM
see https://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/rl-addons/
Exception Location: /base/data/home/apps/s~cacallapp/1.365898222031464318/reportlab/graphics/renderPM.py in <module>, line 32
Python Executable:  /python27_runtime/python27_dist/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/base/data/home/apps/s~cacallapp/1.365898222031464318',
 '/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python27.zip',
 '/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python2.7',
 '/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1',
 '/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/PIL-1.1.7',
 '/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/PIL-1.1.7/PIL',
 '/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4',
 '/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3',
 '/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webob-1.1.1',
 '/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/yaml-3.10',
 '/base/data/home/apps/s~cacallapp/1.365898222031464318/..']
Server time:    Tue, 12 Mar 2013 08:38:21 +0000
```

## Traceback

```
/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                        response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py in _wrapped_view
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/base/data/home/apps/s~cacallapp/1.365898222031464318/CallApp/views.py in gender_chart
    binaryStuff = d.asString('gif')
 ...
▶ Local vars
/base/data/home/apps/s~cacallapp/1.365898222031464318/reportlab/graphics/shapes.py in asString
            from reportlab.graphics import renderPM
 ...
▶ Local vars
/base/data/home/apps/s~cacallapp/1.365898222031464318/reportlab/graphics/renderPM.py in <module>
                                    "see https://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/rl-addons/")
 ...
▶ Local vars
```

Answer (score 1):

PIL is not installed by default with the SDK, since many apps don't need it.  Try installing PIL:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/installingPIL

Also, did you specify PIL in your app.yaml:

```
libraries:
- name: PIL
  version: "latest"
```

Comment: The SDK is for deploying the app on a local server. I'm talking about deploying live on GAE.

Comment: Updated answer: did you add PIL to your app.yaml?

Comment: Try importing PIL by adding it to your app.yaml file as suggested in the answer above if that is the only dependency then it should work.

Comment: It would help if you showed your error logs and stack trace if available.